# How to get current CMS page name

Tags: magento, observers

I am doing via observer to get CMS name which I create.

**config.xml**

```
<events>
   <adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form>
      <observers>
         <my_module_edit_tab_content>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>My_Module_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>changeContent</method>
         </my_module_edit_tab_content>
      </observers>
   </adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_content_prepare_form>
</events>
```

**observer.php**

```
public function changeContent($observer) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to get current CMS page name**

need to use event

```
<cms_page_prepare_save>
               <observers>
                   <sky_slack_page_edit_tab_content>
                       <type>singleton</type>
                       <class>NameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                       <method>addCMS</method>
                   </sky_slack_page_edit_tab_content>
               </observers>
</cms_page_prepare_save>
```

and in observer

```
<?php  
     public function addCMS($observer) {

      $cmsName = $observer->getEvent()->getPage()->getTitle();

     }     
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get CMS page Title like this

```
<?php    
     echo Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getTitle();    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the URL key / identifier of any CMS page in Magento, use the following bit of code.

```
<?php

$cmsPageUrlKey = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();

?>
```

This will return the path that comes after the website’s URL. For example, the URL identifier for the About Us page might be about-us and not the full URL like http://www.yourwebsite.com/about-us/. If you want the full URL including your website address, then you should use the following piece of code.

```
<?php

$cmsPageUrl = Mage::getUrl() . Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the CMS page Title.  If you're on the CMS page, use:

```
<?php
$current_title = Mage::getSingleton(‘cms/page’)->getTitle();
?>
```

If you have the identifier, use:

```
<?php
    Mage::getModel(’cms/page’)->getResource()->getCmsPageTitleByIdentifier(’YOUR_IDE‌​NTIFIER’);
?>
```

(from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102302/get-cms-page-description)